# Neo4j order by "in" clause

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to order results from a query depending on if a value exists in a relationship property (array) or not.

The query I'm trying to run looks like

```
start user=node(1) //id comes from a function
match user-[r:BELONGS_TO]->team
return team, "manager" in r.roles as isManager
order by isManager ASC
```

It simply results "undefined".

Is it not possible or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to take a look at the FILTER function. See the [Cypher refcard](http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/1.9/).

Comment: Combining it with COUNT worked.